# How to import pmml model in python

Tags: python, pyspark, pmml

I created spark pipeline using pyspark and saved pmml model in a file. Now I want to load pmml model back into python. Can someone help me with query to import pmml model into python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to import a pmml file into python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722322/is-there-a-way-to-import-a-pmml-file-into-python)